# Cannot free fileName char * after fclose

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free, realloc

I am trying to free my file name (`char *` pointer) but got an error :

> Heap corruption detected: after normal block (#65) at 0x....

The code:

```
static FILE *initializeIndexFile(char *database, char **indexFileName)
{
    FILE *file1_p;
    *indexFileName = NULL;
    int len = strlen(database);
    *indexFileName = (char *)malloc(len *sizeof(char) + 1);
    strcpy(*indexFileName, database);
    file1_p = fopen(strcat(*indexFileName, ".ind"), "rb");
    if (file1_p == NULL)
        Handle_Failure();
    fclose(file1_p);
    free(*indexFileName);
    return file1_p;
}
```

Firstly I tought it because the file is still open so I make `fclose()` calling but still its got the same error.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Just wanna add, according to your cde, you don't need to get a `char **`, a simple `char *` should be enough here. This may help you debugging some stuff too

Comment: @LeZohan68 Unless he wants the indexFileName in caller function for some purpose.

Comment: @MohitJain if i'm not wrong, it's already a pointer. The content should be modified. And he wants to malloc over, so ...

Comment: @LeZohan68 Yes if he modifies the contents only. If you update a pointer (NULL, malloc etc), you are actually discarding the copy of that pointer and giving new value to your local pointer and the pointer in caller function remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is having issue in the below line

```
strcat(*indexFileName, ".ind")
```

the destination buffer at `*indexFileName` is having insufficient memory to hold the concatenated string. Hence it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) of `strcat()`

> ... If dest (*destination buffer*) is not large enough, program behaviour is unpredictable;

So, once it invokes UB, there is no particular behaviour you can predict or expect.

That said,

1. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to be `1` by `C` standard. You son't need to use that.

**Solution** <sup>[From the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797174/cannot-free-filename-char-after-fclose/30797222#30797222) by Mr. [Mohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659313/mohit-jain)]</sup>

Revise your allocation to:

```
int len = strlen(database) + strlen(".ind");   //allocate enough space to hold
*indexFileName = (char *)malloc(len + 1);      // the final concatenated string
```

Comment: This covers almost everything.

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks sir. Why did you delete your answer? Just now I saw it, it is a good answer. I'm going to _blatantly_ copy the solution part from your answer, with your permission. :-)

Comment: Sure please go ahead. There is no point of 2 similar answers.

Comment: @MohitJain Done. Now it looks complete. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This

`*indexFileName = (char *)malloc( len *sizeof(char) + 1)`;

must be

`*indexFileName = (char *)malloc( len *sizeof(char) + 5);`

due to the extention adding with

`strcat(*indexFileName, ".ind")`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in "strcpy(*indexFileName, database);" instruction,

it should be strcpy(indexFileName, database);